# Defining a type of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, normal-subgroups

I have been tasked with proving the following:

> Let $G= H \times K$ be the direct product of two groups $H$ and $K$. Let $\tilde{H}=\{(h, e_{k});h \in H\}$ and $\tilde{K}=\{(e_{H},k); k \in K\}$. Show that $\tilde{H}$ and $\tilde{K}$ are normal subgroups of $G$.

I know how to prove that something is a subgroup, and I believe I know how to show that it is a normal subgroup.

I am mostly confused on what exactly $\tilde{H}$ and $\tilde{K}$ are. Is that just another label for the groups? If the group name has a tilde on it is there some special property about it?

I know I am overthinking this, but it's the only thing I can't seem to figure out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: They're isomorphic to $H$ and $K$, respectively.

Comment: $\tilde{H}$ and $\tilde K$ are simply notations for the 2 subsets of $G$ defined above. You could as well name them $G_1$ and $G_2.$ You must show that these 2 subsets are normal subgroups.

Comment: $\tilde H = H \times \{e_K\}$ and $\tilde K = \{e_H\} \times K$. One could view $\tilde H$ as the copy of $H$ inside $G$, and similarly for $\tilde K$.

Comment: Re: everyone - So, $\tilde{H}$ is a set isomorphic to $H$ and $G$? Or am I misinterpreting that?

Comment: *Hint:* Consider the map

$$\begin{align}
\varphi:\tilde{H}&\to H,\\
(h, e_k)&\mapsto h.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally if there is an existing object $X$, and there is a new object that is somehow dependent on $X$, it is convention to give the new object a name conveying this dependency.

Common notations include $f(X), Y_X$ (for some choice of letters not necessarily $f$ or $Y$), $\overline{X}, \widetilde{X},$ and most commonly, $X’$.

In this case, the subgroup being specified is uniquely determined by $H$, so we will write it down as $\tilde{H}$ so we don’t forget this relationship.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!