# $G=H \times K$, proving the set generated by $H$ is normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I recently posted a question regarding this same problem, and am looking for further assistance with my proof. The problem is as follows:

> Let $G= H \times K$ be the direct product of two groups $H$ and $K$. Let $\tilde{H}=\{(h, e_{k});h \in H\}$ and $\tilde{K}=\{(e_{H},k); k \in K\}$. Show that $\tilde{H}$ and $\tilde{K}$ are normal subgroups of $G$

[Here was my previous question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4627882/929471)

My start to the proof:

> Let $G= H \times K$ be the direct product of two groups $H$ and $K$. Let $\tilde{H}=\{(h, e_{k});h \in H\}$ and $\tilde{K}=\{(e_{H},k); k \in K\}$.
> $\tilde{H}$ and $\tilde{K}$ are subgroups of $G$ because these sets are subgroups of $H$ and $K$, whose direct product forms the group $G$. We want to see that they are normal in $G$, which is to say we want to see that they are closed under conjugation in $G$. Let $h_{1},h_{2} \in H$ so $(h_{1},e_{K}),(h_{2},e_{K}) \in \tilde{H}$. and $g_{1},g_{2} \in G$.

First, is my statement regarding $\tilde{H}$ and $\tilde{K}$ being subgroups correct, or should I write out the proof that these are subgroups? I thought there was sufficient reasoning to assume without the full proof, but I wanted to be sure. Additionally, to prove they are normal, can I assume that $H$ and $K$ are closed under conjugation, and apply this to the elements of $\tilde{H}$ and $\tilde{K}$ by showing that they are closed as well?

Comment: No, $\overline{H}$ is not a subset of $H$, and $\overline{K}$ is not a subset of $K$. Also, the fact that they are subsets would not imply they are subgroups of $G$. When you write "$\{(h_1,e_K),(h_2,e_K)\}\in \overline{H}$", you are making a categorical error: the item to the left of $\in$ is a set, and this set is not an **element** of $\overline{H}$ (though it *is* a **subset** of $\overline{H}$). In any case, to prove that a subgroup is closed under conjugation, you want to take *one* element of *that* subgroup, and one element of the group. Not two of each.

Comment: You cannot assume $H$ and $K$ are "closed under conjugation". That makes no sense: $H$ and $K$ are separate groups. Closed under conjugation *where*? They aren't subgroups of anything other than themselves, so saying that they are "closed under conjugation" does not parse, and does not help. Your subject line makes a similar error: $H$ is not a subset of $G$, so why are you talking about "the *subgroup* generated by $H$"? Generated *where*? Certainly not in $G$... (and "set generated" does not make sense anyway....)

Comment: I see. How would I go about proving they are subgroups at all, then? Perhaps that's what I am confused about. I will edit the question to properly reflect the elements of $\tilde{H}$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Because they are not answers to the underlying question.

Comment: As you don't actually have (or thought you had) a solution, the solution-verification tag is not appropriate.

Comment: You first identify $H$ with the canonically isomorphic copy of it in $H \times K$, which is $H \times {1_K}$. Then for any $(h_0,1_K) \in H \times {1_K}$ and any $(h,k)\in H \times K$, you have $(h,k)(h_0,1_K)(h,k)^{-1}=(hh_0h^{-1},kk^{-1})=(h',1_K)\in H \times {1_K}$ which is what you wanted.

Comment: @AlexG thank you, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\tilde H,\tilde K$ are easily seen to be groups,
isomorphic to $H,K$ respectively.

Here's an idea:  define $\varphi: H×K\to K$ by $\varphi (h,k)=k.$

It's easy to see that $\varphi $ is a homomorphism with kernel $\tilde H$

But the kernel of a homomorphism is always a normal subgroup.

Comment: I see. I think this approach is much easier than the one I had in mind, which was to show that $\tilde{H}$ was a subgroup, then prove that it is normal. I will re-attempt this using the idea you've shared. Thank you very much!